# Keeping formula references to a deleted sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Perhaps a strange one, but I have a requirement for one worksheet in my workbook to persist any references to a second worksheet after its been deleted.

Essentially, I want to reinsert the sheet again with new data on it (programmatically) so that when it is next opened all the formulas are already pointing to the new data.

I've looked at indirect (), but one of my formulas is:

```
=SUMIFS(
Last36Hours!$K$2:$K$10000, 
Last36Hours!$M$2:$M$10000,"=" &$B$12, 
Last36Hours!$O$2:$O$10000,">" &$B$10, 
Last36Hours!$S$2:$S$10000,"=" & $E13, 
Last36Hours!$Q$2:$Q$10000,">="& TODAY() - (1 - (5.5/24)), 
Last36Hours!$Q$2:$Q$10000,"<"& TODAY()  - (1 - (12.5/24))
)
```

... I couldn't seem to get it to work

Is there a way perhaps I can remove the sheet without opening the file?

Its xlsx by the way (2007)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to not delete the sheet...
I haven't found a system to "Freeze" the reference, but if you copy and paste the entire sheet, you don't have problems with the reference:

```
Dim Base, Prende

Set Base = ActiveWorkbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:="E:\0\New folder\Prende.xlsx"
Set Prende = ActiveWorkbook
Prende.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Copy
Base.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Base.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Base.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Prende.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Accepting as the answer as it was kind of the approach we made in the end. We kept the sheet there, but empty, and just updated it in code.